# Coq extraction to Haskell

Tags: haskell, coq

I have the following Coq implementation of integer division with remainder.
When I extract it to Haskell **everything works fine**. I compared the Coq version to the generated Haskell version and tried to understand what's going on. It seems that `rewrite` **is simply removed here**,
and what actually steers the extraction here are `induction`, `destruct`, `exists` and `specialize`. Is there any scenario where `rewrite` is used during extraction? Also, some variables names are kept (like `q0` and `m0''`) but others change (`r0` to `h`) is there any reason to change names? Here is the Coq code followed by the extracted code:

```
(***********)
(* IMPORTS *)
(***********)
Require Import Coq.Arith.PeanoNat.
Require Import Coq.Structures.OrdersFacts.

Lemma Sn_eq_Sm: forall n m,
  (n = m) -> ((S n) = (S m)).
Proof.
  intros n m H.
  rewrite H.
  reflexivity.
Qed.

Lemma Sn_lt_Sm: forall n m,
  (n < m) -> ((S n) < (S m)).
Proof.
  intros n0 m0 H.
  unfold lt in H.
  apply Nat.lt_succ_r.
  apply H.
Qed.

Lemma add_nSm : forall (n m : nat),
  (n + (S m)) = S (n + m).
Proof.
  intros n m.
  induction n.
  - reflexivity.
  - simpl.
    apply Sn_eq_Sm.
    apply IHn.
Qed.

Lemma n_lt_m: forall n m,
  ((n <? m) = false) -> (m <= n).
Proof.
Admitted.

Lemma n_le_m_le_n: forall n m,
  (n <= m) -> ((m <= n) -> (m = n)).
Proof.
Admitted.

Lemma Sn_ge_0: forall n,
  0 <= (S n).
Proof.
  induction n as [|n' IHn'].
  - apply le_S. apply le_n.
  - apply le_S. apply IHn'.
Qed.

Lemma n_ge_0: forall n,
  0 <= n.
Proof.
  induction n as [|n' IHn'].
  - apply le_n.
  - apply le_S. apply IHn'.
Qed.

Lemma Sn_gt_0: forall n,
  0 < (S n).
Proof.
  induction n as [|n' IHn'].
  - apply le_n.
  - apply le_S. apply IHn'.
Qed.

Lemma n_le_m_implies_Sn_le_Sm: forall n m,
  (n <= m) -> ((S n) <= (S m)).
Proof.
  induction n as [|n' IHn'].
  - induction m as [|m' IHm'].
    + intros H1. apply le_n.
    + intros H1. apply le_S.
      apply IHm'. apply n_ge_0.
  - induction m as [|m' IHm'].
    + intros H1. inversion H1. 
    + intros H1. inversion H1. 
      apply le_n. apply IHm' in H0 as H2.
      apply le_S in H2. apply H2.
Qed.

(****************************************)
(* division with quotient and remainder *)
(****************************************)
Definition div_q_r: forall n m : nat,
   {     q:nat & {     r:nat | (n = q * (S m) + r) /\ (r < (S m))}}.
Proof.
  induction n as [|n' IHn'].
  - exists 0. exists 0. split. reflexivity. apply Sn_gt_0.
  - intros m0.
    destruct m0 as [|m0''] eqn:E1.
    + exists (S n'). exists 0. split.
      * rewrite Nat.add_0_r with (n:=(S n') * 1).
        rewrite Nat.mul_1_r with (n:=(S n')). reflexivity.
      * specialize Sn_gt_0 with (n:=0). intros H. apply H.
    + specialize IHn' with (m:=(S m0'')).
      destruct IHn' as [q0 H]. destruct H as [r0 H].
      destruct (r0 <? (S m0'')) eqn:E2.
      * exists q0. exists (S r0). split.
        -- rewrite add_nSm with (n:=q0 * S (S m0'')). 
           apply Sn_eq_Sm. apply proj1 in H as H1. apply H1.
        -- apply Nat.ltb_lt in E2. apply Sn_lt_Sm. apply E2.
      * exists (S q0). exists 0. split.
        -- apply proj2 in H as H2. rewrite Nat.lt_succ_r in H2.
           apply n_lt_m in E2. apply n_le_m_le_n in H2.
           apply proj1 in H as H1. rewrite H2 in H1. rewrite H1.
           rewrite <- add_nSm with (n:=q0 * S (S m0'')) (m:=S m0'').
           rewrite Nat.add_0_r.
           rewrite Nat.mul_succ_l with (n:=q0) (m:=S (S m0'')).
           reflexivity. apply E2.
        -- unfold "<". apply n_le_m_implies_Sn_le_Sm. apply Sn_ge_0.
Qed.

(********************************)
(* Extraction Language: Haskell *)
(********************************)
Extraction Language Haskell.

(***************************)
(* Use Haskell basic types *)
(***************************)
Require Import ExtrHaskellBasic.

(****************************************)
(* Use Haskell support for Nat handling *)
(****************************************)
Require Import ExtrHaskellNatNum.
Extract Inductive Datatypes.nat => "Prelude.Integer" ["0" "Prelude.succ"]
"(\fO fS n -> if n Prelude.== 0 then fO () else fS (n Prelude.- 1))".

(***************************)
(* Extract to Haskell file *)
(***************************)
Extraction "/home/oren/GIT/some_file_Haskell.hs" div_q_r.
```

And here is the extracted Haskell code:

```
div_q_r :: Prelude.Integer -> Prelude.Integer -> SigT Prelude.Integer
           Prelude.Integer
div_q_r n =
  nat_rec (\_ -> ExistT 0 0) (\n' iHn' m0 ->
    (\fO fS n -> if n Prelude.== 0 then fO () else fS (n Prelude.- 1))
      (\_ -> ExistT (Prelude.succ n')
      0)
      (\m0'' ->
      let {iHn'0 = iHn' (Prelude.succ m0'')} in
      case iHn'0 of {
       ExistT q0 h ->
        let {b = ltb h (Prelude.succ m0'')} in
        case b of {
         Prelude.True -> ExistT q0 (Prelude.succ h);
         Prelude.False -> ExistT (Prelude.succ q0) 0}})
      m0) n
```

Comment: My guess is that `rewrite` never affects the extracted code. It works with type `x=y` in `Prop`, so that disappears. Also, `x=y` could be a mere proposition (e.g. if we admit Streicher's axiom K) making it a data type carrying no information during extraction. (HoTT might change that, though.)

Comment: Your example is not self-contained.  where do `Sn_gt_0`, `Sn_eq_Sm`, `add_nSm` come from?  This makes the work of people who want to help harder.

Comment: @Yves sorry, I added the entire file now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `rewrite`, the goal is actually a type (a formula) and the type of this type is often `Prop`.  When this happens, as in your example, the effect of the `rewrite` tactic is discarded because the part of the term where it took place was discarded.

the extraction tool does not look at tactics: it remove expressions whose type has type `Prop` from the term that will be executed.  The whole system is designed in such a way that these expressions should not have an effect on computation.

In a sense, it is a distinction between compile-time verification and run-time verification.  All the proofs that you do in Coq are compile-time verifications, at run-time they don't need to be redone, so they are removed from the code.  The `Prop` sort is used to mark computations that happen only at compile-time and won't have an effect on the execution at run-time.

You can somehow predict the content of the Haskell extracted program by looking at the result of `Print div_q_r.`

The result contains instances of `existT` and instance of `exist`.  The type of `existT` is :

```
forall (A : Type) (P : A -> Type) (x : A), P x -> {x : A & P x}
```

The notation `{x : A & P x}` is for `@sigT A P`.  In turn the type of `sigT` is

```
forall A : Type, (A -> Type) -> Type
```

The type of `existT P xx pp`  is `@sigT A P` and the type of the latter is `Type`.  In consequence, the extraction tool decides that this term contains data that is important at run time.  Moreover, the second component of `sigT A P`, has type  `P xx` which itself has type `Type`, so this also is important at run time:  it won't be discarded.

Now let's turn our attention to expression of the form `exist _ _`.  Such an expression has type `@sig A P` and `sig` has type :

```
forall A: Type, (A -> Prop) -> Type
```

So an expression `exist Q y qq` contains `y` whose type has type `Type` and `qq` whose type is `Q y` and has type `Prop`.  Information on how to compute `y` will be kept at run time, but information on how to compute `qq` is discarded.

If you want to know where `rewrite` had an effect in the proof, you only need to look for instances of `eq_ind` and `eq_ind_r` in the result of `Print div_q_r.`  You will see that these instances are subterms of the third argument of `exist` statements.  This is the reason why they don't appear in the final result.  It is not because the extraction has special treatement of rewrites, it is because it has a special behavior on the type of types `Prop` (we also call it the *sort* `Prop`).

It is possible to construct functions where `rewrite` leaves a trace in the extraction result, but I am not sure that these functions behave correctly in Haskell.  This when, the formula where the rewrite occur is not in sort `Prop`.

```
Definition nat_type n :=
  match n with O => nat | S p => bool end.

Definition strange n : nat_type (n * 0).
rewrite Nat.mul_0_r.
exact n.
Defined.
```

Comment: I added the missing parts. Note that I deliberately did not prove all lemmas and left some of them (two) as `Admitted`, just to make sure they play no role at the extraction show.

Comment: @Yves I like the step-by-step analysis, but the first paragraph is somehow confusing, since it seems to explain that `rewrite` never has an impact on the extracted term. I think this is not what you intended to write, but it would probably be better to emphasize that this paragraph applies to the particular example shown in the question.

Comment: @eponier: thank you for this comment.  Actually, I changed my mind between two versions of the answer, because I really believed that rewrite would never have an impact.  Then I remembered about an example like the nat_type family of types and I changed my mind.  I will have to rework my answer.  Thanks again.